Weird interaction between the Prima typeface and the libertine package with LuaLaTeX, what's the cause?
I am using the cursive variant of the Prima typeface for some text and stumbled over the following issue.
Without libertine everything looks fine:

However with libertine the result looks weird (in particular look at the third "word"):

The code I used was the following with the latest updates from TeXlive 2024 and LuaLaTeX
\documentclass[convert={size=640}]{standalone}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{libertine} % <-- toggle comment on this line
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\prima{Prima}[Ligatures=TeX]

\begin{document}
    \prima\itshape
    effäh, efföh, effüh, efläh, eflöh, eflüh
\end{document}

Can anyone explain what is going on here? Clearly libertine seems to be modifying some global setting, affecting the other typeface. Initially I even suspected a defect in the typeface, but given the absence of libertine fixes the issue I am no longer certain where the issue lies.

Unfortunately I've never heard of a package "fontspec-luatex". Where does it come from?

\usepackage{fontspec}  then define \newfontfamily\prima then load libertine works fine here. This order prevents the libertine package to apply any feature to \prima.

@DanielFlipo thanks, I'll give this a try tonight. For now I simply removed it, because it was a remnant from a previous iteration of the document and I intend to use the regular typeface version of Prima anyway for this document. However, this got me curious where the problem lies and what approach I can use to diagnose similar issues in the future. Thus the question. The immediate issue is solved by removing the package reference.

you shouldn't use fontspec-luatex.sty directly. You loose the settings from fontspec.sty.

@UlrikeFischer thank you, I fixed that in my documents and adjusted the example above.

The Prima font needs Renderer=HarfBuzz.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine} % <-- toggle comment on this line

\defaultfontfeatures{} % <-- recommended

\newfontfamily\prima{Prima}[
  Extension=.otf,
  Path=./,
  UprightFont=*-Regular,
  ItalicFont=*-Cursive,
  Ligatures=TeX,
  Renderer=HarfBuzz,
]

\newcommand{\printfont}{%
  \expandafter\doprintfont\expandafter{\fontname\font}%
}
\newcommand{\doprintfont}[1]{{\normalfont\tiny\ttfamily#1}}

\begin{document}

\prima\itshape
effäh, efföh, effüh, efläh, eflöh, eflüh

\printfont

\end{document}

If you have Prima installed as a system font you possibly need just
\newfontfamily\prima{Prima}[Renderer=HarfBuzz,Ligatures=TeX]

Output with libertine

Output without libertine

The \printfont command is just to show what are the options for the font, you don't need it in your document.
I also recommend to reset \defaultfontfeatures, because libertine leaves behind a nonstandard setting.

Wow, thank you. Is this something one just has to know about or is there a way you found out that HarfBuzz needs to be used as renderer? Also thanks for the hint about \defaultfontfeatures.

@0xC0000022L I tried and looked at the \fontname in the two cases and the only difference was mode=node for the wrong version and mode=harf for the good one.
